# Submanifold as a preimage of a regular value of a global function

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ (which, for simplicity, is assumed to be compact). Let $N$ be a properly embedded submanifold of codimension $d$. I want to find a sufficient condition to realize $N=f^{-1}(0)$ where $0$ is a regular value of a function $f:M\to \mathbb R^d$.

A necessary condition will be $N$ being co-orientable. If we drop the regular condition of $f$, then this is sufficient. We can just make $f\equiv
\text{constant}$ on the boundary of the tubular neighborhood of $N$, and extend it to $M$.

But, if we require $0$ to be a regular value of $f$, then this is not sufficient. For example, let $M=\mathbb T^2$ and $N=S^1$ as a generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb T^2)$. Then, a tubular neighborhood of $S^1$ will be a strip $S^1\times I$. Now, if $f|_{S^1\times I}:S^1\times I\to \mathbb R$ is the function that satisfies the condition, then $f$ will achieve opposite signs on $S^1\times\partial I$. By intermediate value theorem, $f$ will have a zero in $\mathbb T^2\backslash S^1\times I$.

Another counter-example is as follow. Suppose $N=\{p\}$ is a single point in $M$, and $f:M\to \mathbb R^n$ is the said function. Then $f|_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(p)}:\partial B_{\epsilon}(p)\to \mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}\to S^{n-1}$ has degree $1$. So, it is impossible to extend it to the rest of $M$ without hitting $0$ again.

This suggests that the existence of such $f$ might depend on the (co)homology/(co)homotopy class of $N\subseteq M$. I am not sure how though.

Comment: I am quite sure this was asked before. The answer is trivial normal bundle.

Comment: To clarify: The condition I stated is necessary. It is also sufficient if you want to realize $N$ as a union of components of the preimage rather than full preimage.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As mentioned in the second paragraph, the answer is trivial normal bundle (co-orientable) if we drop the regular condition. But it is not true in general.

Comment: I agree to you if we only need to define $f$ near $N$. I am going to add another counter-example.

Comment: Oh, I remember now: The other MSE question was about regular level sets of maps to spheres, not to $R^d$. For maps to $R^d$ there is also a global obstruction, which, in the case when $N$ is orientable, says that you need $H_{n-d}(N)\to H_{n-d}(M)$ to be zero. As for your question, as asked, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167415/which-submanifolds-are-zero-sets-of-mathbbrn-valued-maps).

Comment: $[N]$ being homologous to zero in $M$ is definitely a necessary condition. I don't know how to show it is sufficient though. And where is the MSE thread for level sets of maps to spheres?

Comment: I will have to look for it. But the proof is straightforward: Since the normal bundle is trivial, you find a submersion $f$ from a tubular neighborhood $T$ of $N$ to $D^d$ such that $N=f^{-1}(0)$. Now, extend $f: \partial T\to \partial D^d$ to a smooth map  $g: M-int(T)\to S^d- int(D^d)$ (since the target is a disk, this extension exists). The maps $f, g$ match at the boundary of $T$ to form a continuous map. Perturb it a bit to make it smooth everywhere.